# How to Substitute a String if record is NULL in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, null

I'm writing a T-SQL report that shows the number of accounts that are in different statuses for different customers. The report results in something like:

```
Customer1    NoService        7
Customer1    IncompleteOrder  13
Customer1    NULL             9
Customer2    NoService        12
Customer2    Available        19
Customer2    NULL             3
...
```

The 'NULL' status is valid data, but instead of displaying NULL, I want to display "Pending". Here is my SQL so far:

```
USE cdwCSP;
SELECT
   sr.sales_region_name   AS SalesRegion
   , micv.value
   , COUNT(sr.sales_region_name)
FROM prospect p
   LEFT JOIN sales_region sr
     ON p.salesRegionId = sr.sales_region_number
   LEFT JOIN prospectOrder po
     ON po.prospectId = p.prospectId
   LEFT JOIN wo
     ON wo.prospectId = p.prospectId
   LEFT JOIN woTray wot
     ON wot.woId = wo.woId
   LEFT JOIN miscInformationCustomerCategory micc
     ON micc.prospectId = p.prospectId
   LEFT JOIN miscInformationCustomerValues micv
     ON micv.miscInformationCustomerCategoryId = micc.miscInformationCustomerCategoryId
   LEFT JOIN miscInformationCategory mic
     ON micc.miscInformationCategoryId = mic.miscInformationCategoryId
WHERE wot.dateOut IS NULL
     AND mic.categoryName LIKE '%Serviceability%'
GROUP BY sr.sales_region_name, micv.value
ORDER BY sr.sales_region_name, micv.value;
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm still learning T-SQL so this might be an easy question to answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) or `ISNULL`. The former is standard and returns the first `NOT NULL` argument (or `NULL` if all arguments are `NULL`)

```
SELECT COALESCE(micv.value,'Pending') as value
```

`ISNULL` is restricted to only 2 arguments but is more efficient in SQL Server if the first value to be tested is expensive to evaluate (e.g. a subquery).

One potential "gotcha" with `ISNULL` to be aware of is that it returns the datatype of the first parameter so if the string to be substituted is longer than the column datatype would allow you will need a cast.

E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE T(C VARCHAR(3) NULL);

INSERT T VALUES (NULL);

SELECT ISNULL(C,'Unknown')
FROM T
```

Would return `Unk`

But `ISNULL(CAST(C as VARCHAR(7)),'Unknown')` or `COALESCE` would both work as desired.

Comment: Perfect, this works well and seems efficient. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `ISNULL('value', 'replacewithvalue')`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   sr.sales_region_name   AS SalesRegion
   , ISNULL(micv.value,'Pending')
   , COUNT(sr.sales_region_name)
FROM prospect p
--(...)
```

Go check [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms184325.aspx) for further info.