# sql srss show rows without value

Tags: sql, sql-server, return-value, rows

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(H.RootID) AS [Anzahl], hlrpttreeitem.displaypath AS Kategorie, DATEPART(month, SRQuery.Datum) AS [Monat]
FROM sereresystem
INNER JOIN sereregeneral ON sereresystem.caseid = sereregeneral.caseid
INNER JOIN sereresperou ON sereresystem.caseid = sereresperou.caseid
INNER JOIN sererekeywordskeyword ON sereresystem.caseid = sererekeywordskeyword.caseid
INNER JOIN Hierarchy H ON sererekeywordskeyword.sererekeywordskeywordid = H.childid
INNER JOIN SRQuery ON sereresystem.referencenumber = SRQuery.Ticketnummer
INNER JOIN SRInnerQuery ON SRQuery.Ticketnummer = SRInnerQuery.Ticketnummer
LEFT JOIN hlrpttreeitem ON hlrpttreeitem.treeitemid = H.RootID
WHERE (sereregeneral.inpcha NOT IN (102800, 102993))
AND (sereresperou.assrol IN (102961, 107075, 107074))
AND hlrpttreeitem.languageid = '7'
AND (DATEPART(month, sereresystem.registrationtime) IN (@Monat))
AND (DATEPART(year, sereresystem.registrationtime) = @Jahr)
AND SRQuery.Anzahl = SRInnerQuery.Anzahl
GROUP BY hlrpttreeitem.displaypath, DATEPART(month, SRQuery.Datum)
```

In SRSS i use a matrix to create a list of categorys (about 20) as rows, and count an amount of values for each month of the year per category.

There are some categorys which don´t have values in it.

My Problem is now, that i want them to show in the list of categorys with the value "0".

I´ve read things about left join or outer joins, but can´t get them to work.
Does anybody know how i can

Comment: Are you using MDX for this?

Comment: I´m using the Microsoft SQL Reporting Services.

Comment: You'll want to use the NONEMPTY keyword http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145626.aspx

Comment: Seems like i can´t use thenonempty keyword... I always get an error

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Hm... i´ve looked again and it´s said that srss supports MDX, but my query is just T-SQL. Honestly i havn´t worked with mdx before.

Comment: Take a look at this previous post, I think you will need a LEFT JOIN and use the ISNULL() selector http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518802/how-to-substitute-a-string-if-record-is-null-in-t-sql