# SQL: How to make a query which takes a possible null value into respect according to my specific task?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Table1

Col1|Col2
----|----
AAAA|1111
BBBB|2222
CCCC|3333
CCCC|4444
```

Following query is given:

```
SELECT Col1,Col2 from Table1 where Col1+Col2 like 'CCCC%'
```

**This works**. It returns row 3 and row 4 as expected.

Now there is another table which holds data like following:

```
Table2

Col1|Col2   
----|----    
AAAA|1111    
CCCC|
```

Now I want to get AAAA|1111 and BOTH of CCCC rows from Table 1.

Therefore I made the columns of Table2 like following:

```
Col1 varchar(50) DEFAULT ('%')
Col2 varchar(50) DEFAULT ('%')
```

And finally, if I use both tables "together", following query is used:

```
SELECT Col1,Col2 where Col1+Col2 in (SELECT Col1+Col2 FROM Table2)
```

=> It does only return the AAAA|1111, but NOT CCCC-rows.
Conclusion: The DEFAULT value '%' is either

- a) not set at all or
- b) not taken into respect

How can I resolve this?

Thank you very much!

Edit:

1. No, I can not change the whole "idea behind this"
2. Yes, I am fully aware of the possibility that the "empty" field in Table2.Col2 could be a space-character or something else, but it is 100% sure NULL

Comment: If your one column is null then concatenation gives you null result. You have to use coalesce. coalesce(col1, '')+ coalesce(col2,'')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Substitute a String if record is NULL in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518802/how-to-substitute-a-string-if-record-is-null-in-t-sql)

Comment: Your description of what you want is unclear. What do you want output as a function of what input? What are all possible inputs? Please use entire sentences to explain clearly, not sentence fragments. Or examples when you have not explained what they are examples of. Please also read and act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NB: `in` performs an `=` against values in a list; not a `like`.  I think that's the root of your issue.  Try instead:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 
from Table1 t1    
where exists (
    SELECT top 1 1 
    from Table2 t2
    where t1.Col1 + t1.Col2 like t2.Col1 + t2.Col2 
)
```

NB: Rather than defaulting values to '%' you can replace nulls at runtime using the `isnull` or `coalesce` functions.  i.e.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 
from Table1 t1    
where exists (
    SELECT top 1 1 
    from Table2 t2
    where t1.Col1 + t1.Col2 like coalesce(t2.Col1, '%') + coalesce(t2.Col2, '%') 
)
```

Whilst the above is slower than using the default values approach (i.e. because we're using functions at runtime rather than a one off when the row's inserted), it likely makes more sense to leave the value as null rather than using a default value to hold something code specific.

---

**Full Runnable Example**

```
create table Table1 (
    Col1 varchar(10) not null
    ,Col2 varchar(10) not null
)

create table Table2 (
    Col1 varchar(10) default '%'
    ,Col2 varchar(10) default '%'
)
go
insert Table1 (Col1, Col2)
values
 ('AAAA', '1111')
,('BBBB', '2222')
,('CCCC', '3333')
,('CCCC', '4444')

insert Table2 (Col1, Col2)
values
 ('AAAA', '1111')
,('CCCC', default)

select Col1, Col2 
from Table1 t1    
where exists (
    select top 1 1 
    from Table2 t2
    where t1.Col1 + t1.Col2 like t2.Col1 + t2.Col2 
)
```

Comment: Thanks, the second attempt worked!
The first, though, did not return all of "CCCC".
I am still curious why, though. The '%' default does not seem to work at all

Comment: Very odd; what data type are those columns?  Potentially if `nchar(`#`)` (or `char(`#`)` rather than `nvarchar(`#`)`/`varchar(`#`)` the `%` value may have been right padded with spaces?  However, I'm not sure.

Comment: Another thought... Have you checked that `%` is showing as the value of the column you expect to have been defaulted?  NB: if rows were inserted before you set the default value, or if you explicitly inserted the value `null` into that column, that field will be null.  The default's only used if you omit to include a value for that column when inserting; or if you explicitly use the keyword `default` for the value.

Comment: Full example code added for the first statement, so you can see this working.